# Unable to get gthub packages to import in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

https://github.com/Miker2808/PyRoboteq

I am trying to use this github package for motor control of a robot. I have been unable to get it to work in vscode, and have tried a few different ways of installing the package. I thought there was something wrong with the package, but I tried to use the same way to install a known package like flask, yet I still get the error below when trying to install the package.

I tried pip3 install (package), that ran correctly and it showed up when I ran pip freeze, but I was unable to import the package in my code.

Here is the error i got when trying to install flask:

```
sudo pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/pallets/flask#egg=flask
Obtaining flask from git+https://github.com/pallets/flask#egg=flask
  Cloning https://github.com/pallets/flask to ./src/flask
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/pallets/flask /home/chase/src/flask
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/chase/src/flask/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/chase/src/flask/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
         cwd: /home/chase/src/flask/
    Complete output (35 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/chase/src/flask/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
        dist.parse_config_files()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 701, in parse_config_files
        parse_configuration(self, self.command_options,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 121, in parse_configuration
        meta.parse()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 426, in parse
        section_parser_method(section_options)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 399, in parse_section
        self[name] = value
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 184, in __setitem__
        value = parser(value)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 515, in _parse_version
        version = self._parse_attr(value, self.package_dir)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 349, in _parse_attr
        module = import_module(module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/chase/src/flask/src/flask/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from . import json as json
      File "/home/user/src/flask/src/flask/json/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from jinja2.utils import htmlsafe_json_dumps as _jinja_htmlsafe_dumps
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Do I have to change something in vscode so it can access the packages I installed?

I tried multiple weays of installing package, unable to use the package anyway.

Comment: Your setup depends on having `jinja2` installed before you can install this other package. (This is not a Git or GitHub item, it's just a case that one package depends on another, probably with a missing declaration of dependencies.)

Comment: I’m pretty new to python. Only have used the built in numpy packages for data analysis so I’m not completely sure I know what you mean. So since it’s not git, in my ubuntu terminal I can run “sudo apt-get jinja2” ?

Comment: Generally, people install Python requirements using `pip` and/or a `requirements.txt` file. Whether simply installing jinja2 that way works, I have no idea: I have not used any of these packages.